# Sql Parameters passing with @parameter = value type

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlparameter

I am using an accounting program. I want to implement one feature of this program to my C# application. Accounting Program uses MS SQL database. So I have looked up SQL trace logs via SQL Server Profiler.

Accounting Program sends this command to database that i want to implement in my app:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE "MyDB".."MyTable"
 SET "CARDREF"=@P1,"DATE_"=@P2,"MODULENR"=@P3,"SIGN"=@P4,"FICHEREF"=@P5,
"FICHELINEREF"=@P6,"TRCODE"=@P7,"TOTAL"=@P8,(....)
WHERE "LOGICALREF"=@P78 AND "CARDREF"=@P79 AND "DATE_"=@P80 AND "MODULENR"=@P81
 AND "SIGN"=@P82 AND (...),

N'@P1 int,@P2 datetime,@P3 smallint,@P4 smallint,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 smallint,
@P8 float,@P9 float,@P10 float,@P11 float,@P12 int,@P13 smallint,@P14 smallint (....),

12309,'2016-01-01 00:00:00',5,0,1417,0,14,1126,9000000000001,(.....)
```

I implemented this query to my app but i have a problem. My app sends parameter values like this (From SQL Server Profiler Trace Logs):

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE "MyDB".."MyTable"
 SET "CARDREF"=@P1,"DATE_"=@P2,"MODULENR"=@P3,
"SIGN"=@P4,"FICHEREF"=@P5,"FICHELINEREF"=@P6,"TRCODE"=@P7,"TOTAL"=@P8,(....)
 WHERE "LOGICALREF"=@P78 AND "CARDREF"=@P79 AND "DATE_"=@P80 AND "MODULENR"=@P81
 AND "SIGN"=@P82 AND (...),

 N'@P1 int,@P2 datetime,@P3 smallint,@P4 smallint,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 smallint, @P8 float,
@P9 float,@P10 float,@P11 float,@P12 int,@P13 smallint,@P14 smallint (....),    


@P1=12309,@P2='2016-04-17 00:00:00',@P3=6,@P4=0,@P5=181,@P6=1068,@P7=3,@P8=5138,8999999999996,
 @P9=5138,8999999999996,@P10=0,@P11=0,@P12=11636,@P13=0,@P14=0,(...)
```

You see my app's parameter values passing like this; @Parameter = value. Not like the accounting program. (Only parameter value, without @Parameter tag.)

Here's my code below;

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE"))
            {
                SqlTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                cmd.Transaction = trans;
                cmd.Connection = connection;


            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET CARDREF=@P1,DATE_=@P2,MODULENR=@P3,
SIGN=@P4,FICHEREF=@P5,FICHELINEREF=@P6, TRCODE=@P7,TOTAL=@P8,PAID=@P9,
EARLYINTRATE=@P10,LATELYINTRATE=@P11,CROSSREF=@P12,PAIDINCASH=@P13,CANCELLED=@P1
4,PROCDATE=@P15,TRCURR=@P16,TRRATE=@P17,REPORTRATE=@P18(....)
 WHERE LOGICALREF=@P78 AND CARDREF=@P79 AND DATE_=@P80 AND MODULENR=@P81 AND      SIGN=@P82
 AND FICHEREF=@P83 AND FICHELINEREF=@P84 AND TRCODE=@P85 AND TOTAL=@P86 AND     PAID=@P87
 AND EARLYINTRATE=@P88 AND LATELYINTRATE=@P89 AND CROSSREF=@P90";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ptrns1.CARDREF;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ptrns1.DATE_;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P3", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = ptrns1.MODULENR;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P4", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = ptrns1.SIGN;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P5", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ptrns1.FICHEREF;               
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P6", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ptrns1.FICHELINEREF;
                (......)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? It is not quite clear from your question - what are you asking....

Comment: I'm guessing, based on your trace, that your issue is you are supplying floats in your locale-specific format (i.e. comma rather than period for the decimal point), whereas the locale of the database might be different. Do you have the actual error message your sql returns?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I edited the post. Have take a look again.

Comment: @dash There is no error messages thrown. But update fails beacuse no records supplies where condition cause of passing parameters @parameter=value type.

Comment: @erhanzeyrek so if you run the SQL against the database directly does it work? If the record doesn't exist, you can't update it and would instead need to insert it.

Comment: Are you doing trans.Commit() ?